# EndNote 7.5 installation issue on (yes) Windows XP: "Error applying transforms. Verify..."

Tags: windows, windows-installer, transform, windows-xp-sp3

EndNote has been playing up for days for me and I've been meaning to upgrade from v6.0 to v7.0/v7.5. I don't know how it is for others but I think we have an institutional copy of EndNote that comes as an .exe. This .exe expands to: Install.cmd, Thomson Reuters Endnote (TRE) X7.5.MSI, TRE X7.5.mst and TRE X7.51.cab.

If you extract the .exe, you can click on the .MSI to try to install EndNote but it apparently does it without a license, so you're given the choice of purchasing a license or trialing the software for 30 days. However, if you click on Install.cmd, which is the script that the .exe runs if you click on the .exe itself, I get an error message: "Error applying transforms. Verify that the specified transform paths are valid." (against the background cmd.exe, with "C:\Documents and Settings[Username]\Desktop>msiexec.exe /i "Thomson Reuters Endnote X7.5.MSI" TRANSFORMS="Thomson Reuters Endnote X7.5.mst" /qb).

For context, I've recently (re)installed Microsoft Windows Installer 4.5 on my Windows XP computer running Service Pack 3 and those issues I've been having with EndNote 6.0 were to do with network issues, namely, Windows errors 12029 ("resolved" by resetting all settings in otherwise unused Internet Explorer 8.0) and 12157. If anyone has any tips on resolving these, mainly the latter now, or the EndNote 7.5 installation issue, that would be appreciated. Thanks.